# htaccess static url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on wordpress blog and the its has the url pattern something like this. **localhost/blog/2012/10/12/sample-post/** .

Now i have updated the url pattern to **localhost/blog/sample-post/**.

Now i need a redirection to second URL pattern if someone enters the first URL Pattern as i have already submitted URLs with first pattern to couple of articles.

i.e, **localhost/blog/2012/10/12/sample-post/** should be redirected to  **localhost/blog/sample-post/**

Can anyone assist me by providing htacess code ?

Comment: Apaches mod_rewrite comes with an excellent documentation that includes good examples covering exactly what you are looking for. Read that documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these to the htaccess file in your document root. Make sure they are *before* any wordpress related rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blog/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @SyamKumar [Works perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5RzFk.png), blank htaccess file and new apache install.

Comment: I have added the above code  in top of below code          `RewriteEngine off
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
 suPHP_ConfigPath /home/peopleco/public_html/blog/php.ini
 <Files php.ini>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
 </Files>
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
`   Can you please guide me where exactly i need to place. I am totally newbie in working with htaccess file.